# tkinter change image with if-else condition

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

in the below code,

```
card_front_image = PhotoImage(file="images/card_front.png")
card_back_image = PhotoImage(file="images/card_back.png")
card_background = canvas.create_image(400, 263, image=card_front_image)
```

i want to change the image of a canvas image by condition like that:

if canvas image == image card_front_image - change it to card_back_image.

(the change will be done with button)

but how can i get hold the canvas image to compare it to variable?

thanks!

Comment: Don't compare the image.  Keep a separate boolean flag that tells you which is current.

Comment: You can use `canvas.itemcget(card_background, "image")` to get the current option setting as a string.  Note that this won't compare as equal to the PhotoImage object itself, but you can compare it to `str(card_front_image)` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Use another variable to indicate which image you're showing.

```
card_front_image = PhotoImage(file="images/card_front.png")
card_back_image = PhotoImage(file="images/card_back.png")
card_background = canvas.create_image(400, 263, image=card_front_image)
showing_front = True
...
if showing_front:
    card_background = canvas.create_image(400, 263, image=card_back_image)
    showing_front = False
else:
    card_background = canvas.create_image(400, 263, image=card_front_image)
    showing_front = True
```